# JavaScript RegEx Troubles - Matching then Splitting

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I am trying to match a pattern of numbers/words and then split on that grouping into an array. I have a regex pattern that seems to identify things properly (for the most part). Using RegExr.com I have made this:

http://regexr.com/3h7d2

It is ALMOST Correct. I cannot see why it will not get the word "crumbs" in bread crumbs.

I want to split on each ingredient and then push each one into an index in an array.

I have tried:

```
var regExp = '/(\d+)([^\d]+) |(\d+\/\d+) [^\d]+ /g';
cleanedText = ingredients.split(regExp);
console.log(cleanedText);
```

This does not work. It's not splitting at all. It's looking for [number space words] | [or Fraction space Words] and should split on each one it finds.

Comment: Learned something new here. I didn't know you could do multiple splits in one call. I know you can do multiple removes and replaces, but I never knew you could do it on splits. Very cool

Comment: Wait, but "bread crumbs" doesn't have any numbers, to begin with, nor is there a `|` so how are you expecting it to work?

Comment: Please add the relevant text you are searching for.

Comment: I was thinking it would do 1/3 cup bread crumbs... just like it did 1/2 onion, diced    It has to split up this sort of input into individual ingredients...   3 strips bacon 6 large mushrooms 1 tablespoon butter 1lb - Simply Balanced 1/2 onion, diced 1 clove garlic, sliced 3 ounces cream cheese 3 ounces blue cheese 1/3 cup bread crumbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/((\d+\/\d+|\d+)\s*)([^\d]+)/g
```

I like regex101.com better. They provide much more information on what is going on in your RegExp.

See my example:

https://regex101.com/r/nY1Hmh/2

This RegExp works for integers like:

- *`3` Cups* or
- *`1`lb flour*

and fractions like

- *`1/3` teaspoons*

BTW: If you use `match` instead of `split` then you get back an array that provides you the number and the rest of the string. Just in case you wanted to separate those as well.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing space after the last+

Use match instead of split

Swap regex groups, first the one with /, and after that the usual one

```
cleanedText = ingredients.match(/(\d+\/\d+)[^\d]+|(\d+)([^\d]+)/g);
```

```js
var ingredients = '3 strips bacon 6 large mushrooms 1 tablespoon butter 1lb - Simply Balanced 1/2 onion, diced 1 clove garlic, sliced 3 ounces cream cheese 3 ounces blue cheese 1/3 cup bread crumbs';
cleanedText = ingredients.match(/(\d+\/\d+)[^\d]+|(\d+)([^\d]+)/g);
console.log(cleanedText);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me this:   ["", "3", " strips bacon", undefined, "", "6", " large mushrooms", undefined, "", "1", " tablespoon butter", undefined, "", "1", "lb - Simply Balanced", undefined, "", undefined, undefined, "1/2", "", "1", " clove garlic, sliced", undefined, "", "3", " ounces cream cheese", undefined, "", "3", " ounces blue cheese", undefined, "", undefined, undefined, "1/3", ""]    It's not splitting correctly for some reason.

Comment: than you need to use match

Answer (score 1):

Ok, why isn't your regex matching bread crumbs? Because you are matching all the words that ends with a space, and since "bread crumbs" is the last word, it won't get matched.

Regular expressions are sensitive to whitespaces, so remove them from:

```
/(\d+)([^\d]+)|(\d+\/\d+)([^\d]+)/g
```

Then, the [split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) works differently than what you expect.
Probably you mean to use the *match* method:

```
var sentence = "3 strips bacon 6 large mushrooms 1 tablespoon butter 1lb - Simply Balanced 1/2 onion, diced 1 clove garlic, sliced 3 ounces cream cheese 3 ounces blue cheese 1/3 cup bread crumbs"; 
var ingredients = sentence.match(/(\d+)([^\d]+)|(\d+\/\d+)([^\d]+)/g);
```

It returns an array which each element is a matched group.

Edit:
This regex fixes the problems with fractions:

```
/(\d+)([^(\d\/)]+)|(\d+\/\d+)([^\d]+)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can split by spaces that are before a digit [`\ (?=\d)\g`](https://regex101.com/r/ErfKlp/1)

```js
s = '3 strips bacon 6 large mushrooms 1 tablespoon butter 1lb - Simply Balanced 1/2 onion, diced 1 clove garlic, sliced 3 ounces cream cheese 3 ounces blue cheese 1/3 cup bread crumbs'

console.log(s.split(/ (?=\d)/g))
```